# Python (NumPy): Memory efficient array multiplication with fancy indexing

Tags: python, numpy, memory, vectorization

I'm looking to do fast matrix multiplication in python, preferably NumPy, of an array A with another array B of repeated matrices by using a third array I of indices. This can be accomplished using fancy indexing and matrix multiplication:

```
from numpy.random import rand, randint

A = rand(1000,5,5)
B = rand(40000000,5,1)
I = randint(low=0, high=1000, size=40000000)

A[I] @ B
```

However, this creates the intermediate array `A[I]`  of shape (40000000, 5, 5) which overflows the memory. It seems highly inefficient to have to repeat a small set of matrices for multiplication, and this is essentially a more general version of broadcasting such as `A[0:1] @ B` which has no issues.

Are there any alternatives?

I have looked at NumPy's einsum function but have not seen any support for utilizing an index vector in the call.

Comment: Could you iterate `for i in range(1000):`, and do `A[i]@B` and assign the resulting `(40...,5,1)` arrays to slots in a preallocated (40...,5,1) array.  Wait that doesn't make sense.  I'm having problems picturing how the 'small set' maps on to the final result.  Or how about iterating on the 2nd dimension of `A`?  Just 5 times.  Then you only need to generate (40...,1,5,1) results at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're open to another package, you could wrap it up with dask.

```
from numpy.random import rand, randint
from dask import array as da

A = da.from_array(rand(1000,5,5))
B = da.from_array(rand(40000000,5,1))
I = da.from_array(randint(low=0, high=1000, size=40000000))

fancy = A[I] @ B
```

[image: fancy desc]

After finished manipulating, then bring it into memory using `fancy.compute()`

Comment: This solves the problem. Also dask was new to me so I will dig a bit more in this package to see what it offers.
Thanks for the support!