# Concatenating Numpy arrays of different shapes (my approach works fine but the data consume too much memory)

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have two Numpy arrays of different shapes, and I am concatenating them. But it takes too much memory and as a result creates/generates a conatenated array of very large size of about 74 GB, while my 1st array is of size 16 GBs and the 2nd array is of size 7 KBs. My data is of this shape.

```
(380, 16, 512, 512)
(380, 4)
```

And my code for concatenating these two arrays is below:

```
a = np.reshape(a, (380, 16, 512, 512, 1))
b = np.reshape(b, (380, 4, 1))
b = np.transpose(b, [0, -1, 1])
b = np.repeat(b, 16, axis=1)

b = np.reshape(b, (380, 16, 4 ,1, 1))
b = np.transpose(b, [0, 1, -1, -2, 2])
b = np.repeat(b, 512, axis=2)
b = np.repeat(b, 512, axis=3)

train_data = np.concatenate([a, b], axis=-1)
```

As I mentioned about the code works fine but I need a way to concatenate both arrays that will produce a new merged array of less size i.e. 32, 33 GB's. Please tell me what method should I apply for this purpose.

The resultant array I need is of the shape.

```
(380, 16, 512, 512, 5)
```

Thanks.

Comment: That new shape is 5x larger than the original `a`.  How you construct it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: You could make a `res = np.zeros((380,16,512,512,5), dtype=a.dtype)` array, and copy `a` and `b` to that.  `res[...,0] = a`, `res[...,1:] = b[:,None,None,None,:]`.  But `res` is still the large size.  `res` ends up with 4 copies of `b`.  You might want to rethink why you are trying to do this concatenation.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for your answer, I will check this approach. Actually the first Numpy array of shape (380, 16,512, 512, 1) contain images 380 are total observations/samples and each sample contains 16 frames/images while 512x512 is images/frames length and height and the 2nd Numpy array conains some features in text form in 4 columns, which I need to add to every observation/sample and train a ML algorithm.

Comment: Your image is probably float or some smaller numeric dtype.  `features` in text form will have a very different `dtype`.  You don't want to combine those into one array.  Even when sizes are ok, the result will be a pure text dtype  array, not a mixed dtypes.  You need to study your ML to clearer idea of how to use both images and text features.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your array operations in a library purpose built for big data/ out-of-memory operations. [Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/array.html) is one I'm most familiar with, but others exist. See this answer to a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74658009/5373105